# What code do I add to a .js file to define "start", to fix the Invalid Block Definition?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, block, google-blockly

I'm new to Blockly. To learn how to create a Custom Block, I used https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/toolbox#json. I copied portions of this text to an HTML file:

```
'''
<body>
<div id="blocklyDiv"></div>
<script>
  var toolbox = 
  {
    "kind": "categoryToolbox",
    "contents": [
      {
        "kind": "category",
        "name": "Core",
        "contents": [
          {
            "kind": "block",
            "type": "controls_if"
          },
          {
            "kind": "block",
            "type": "logic_compare"
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "kind": "category",
        "name": "Custom",
        "contents": [
          {
            "kind": "block",
            "type": "start"
          },
          {
            "kind": "category",
            "name": "Move",
            "contents": [
              {
                "kind": "block",
                "type": "move_forward"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "kind": "category",
            "name": "Turn",
            "contents": [
              {
                "kind": "block",
                "type": "turn_left"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {toolbox: toolbox});
</script>
```

```
'''
```

Using VSCode -> F5 --- results in this on a Chrome browser -> https://snipboard.io/ToY9UW.jpg

Selecting the "Custom" icon -> https://snipboard.io/X9WIFH.jpg, the VSCode "Debug Console" shows -> https://snipboard.io/qkpXCi.jpg.

What code do I add to a .js file to define "start", to fix the Invalid Block Definition?

Comment: I think you are looking for [this (custom blocks)](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/custom-blocks#json_array) ... in short you need a js file with a call to `Blockly.defineBlocksWithJsonArray` to define your `start` custom block and include that js in your html

Answer (score 0):

Diego D --- That is exactly what I need! The key is
"Blockly.defineBlocksWithJsonArray()" as defined at https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/custom-blocks#json_array.